# Get End Date by adding two form fields

Tags: php, javascript, html, forms

I have a form in a webpage where I want the user to enter a start date and then choose a term from a select field to determine the end date.

I can get normal numbers to add up but I don't know how to add a number to a date to get another date.

Here's what I've used so far:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function sum(){
  //grab the values
  startdate = document.getElementById('startdate').value;
  term = document.getElementById('term').value;

  document.getElementById('enddate').value = parseFloat(startdate) + parseFloat(term);
  }
  </script>
<p>
<label for="startdate">Start Date:</label>
<input type="date" name="start-date" id="startdate" onblur="sum()">
</p>
<p>
<label for="term">Term:</label>
<select name="term" id="term" onblur="sum()">
<option value="30">30 Days</option>
<option value="60">60 Days</option>
<option value="90">90 Days</option>
</select>
</p>
<p>
<label for="enddate">End Date:</label>
<input name="enddate" type="date" id="enddate" readonly>
</p>
```

This sample doesn't yield a date and only responds to the initial select value. The resulting data will be inserted into a mySQL database using PHP.

Answer (score 1):

Use it like this, it will add the number of days and create end date.

```
var someDate = new Date(document.getElementById('startdate').value);
var numberOfDaysToAdd = document.getElementById('term').value;
document.getElementById('enddate').value = someDate.setDate(someDate.getDate() + numberOfDaysToAdd);
```

Comment: I'm not seeing a different result when I choose options from the select.